# Ошибка линковщика asm

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Ребята, скажите, знающие, что не так.
Компилирую ассемблеровский файл (masm32) , компилируется, а линковщик ругается:

**warning LNK4033: converting object format from OMF to COFF**

потом не может создать исполняемый файл
Что делать?
Рунет ответов не даёт, может кто встречал такую ошибку, подскажите

компилируемый файл:

```
TITLE тестовый файл (try.asm)
.386
.model flat, stdcall

INCLUDE C:\masm32\include\Kernel32.inc

.data
        stra BYTE "Mystring is this!", 0
        namesize = ($-stra) - 1
.code
   main PROC
        mov esi, 0        ; индекс-смещение  
        mov ecx, namesize ; счётчик для LOOP
        L1:               ; загружаем строку в стек посимвольно
                movzx eax, stra[esi]
                push eax
                inc esi
                LOOP L1
        mov esi, 0
        mov ecx, namesize
        L2:               ; выбираем строку из стека
                pop eax
                mov stra[esi], al
                inc esi
                LOOP L2
        INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
    main ENDP
END main
```

Вот, а вот что говорит компилятор на это:

```
C:\Users\Ian Lekaspid>cd C:\masm32\progs

C:\masm32\progs>ml try.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: try.asm
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

/z2
"try.obj"
"try.exe"
NUL
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "z2"; ignored
try.obj : warning LNK4033: converting object format from OMF to COFF
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "try.exe"

C:\masm32\progs>
```

P.S. системная переменная Path: C:\masm32\bin как и требуется, если это важно :\

Comment: Наши штатные телепаты в отпусках, к сожалению. Поэтому, чёрт побери, покажите полные командные строки/ключи всех утилит. Если не затруднит, конечно.

Comment: Разумеется
Компилирую строкой ml [name].asm
Компилятор пишет Assembling...
потом работает линковщик
Сначала в недоумении от какого-то ключа /z2, игнорирует его
Потом пишет эту ошибку
А дальше соответственно: не могу открыть [prog].exe
[prog] - имя программы
Если что-то упустил, укажите

Comment: @mrexox: Попробуйте найти минимальный .asm-файл, который выдаёт такой результат, и выложите в вопросе. Также перенесите туда используемые ком. строки. И выложите полный лог компиляции.

Comment: @VladD пожалуйста, подскажите, как решить этот вопрос.

Comment: @mrexox: О, уже лучше. Посмотрите, кажется, [вот здесь](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?topic=18130.0) описывается похожая проблема. Там предлагают bat-файл с ключами.

---
update: вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19602279/276994) советуют компилировать так:

    ml /c /coff /Cp try.asm
    link /subsystem:windows try.obj

Comment: спасибо за ресурсы, однако компилируя так как написано на втором ресурсе, увы .exe не запускается

Comment: Опять спросил дежурных телепатов - не, говорят, отдыхают. Так что придётся как-то пояснить, что значит "exe не запускается".

Comment: остроумно.
это значит я кликаю два раза по exeшнику и ничего не происходит, курсор меняется на время, а потом, будто вызова и не происходило, даже консоль не кажет

Comment: @mrexox: Так это и нормально. Ваша программа же ничего и не делает. Консоль и не появится: вы ж её [не вызываете](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)! На ассемблере всё делать надо вручную.

Ваша программа скорее всего молча отрабатывает и успешно завершается, ничего не выводя на экран.

Comment: @mrexox, вариантов для "exe не запускается" существует куда больше одного, и все со своей диагностикой и симптоматикой. Так что старайтесь приводить как можно больше подробностей, потому что телепаты действительно в отпуске.
А в вашем случае что происходить должно? Запустите программу в отладчике и пройдитесь пошагово.